# OpenGL ES - drawing smooth lines

Tags: ios, opengl-es, drawing, gl-triangle-strip

I am drawing lines using this code

```
glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, serieLine[serie_i]);
            glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribColor, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, colors[serie_i]);
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, count/2);
```

but the result is sometimes kinda creepy, like this
[image]

I know that by using GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP I might get better results, but every algorithm I've tried so far to calculate triangles gets me no result or very strange one. 
Any idea to get better one will be appreciated.

Comment: may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338696/how-to-draw-anti-aliased-lines-in-opengl-es-2-0?rq=1

Comment: Yeah that is "creepy." Do you have any other states enabled? Like texture mapping? I would almost blame some of the ugly behavior on improper usage of `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` but of course this is ES, which does not even have that feature. I will give you my usual rant about floating-point colors though, do not use them! =P They waste VRAM and bus bandwidth when you send the vertices to the VRAM, use ... 4, `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE`, ... in your vertex attrib pointers, and point them to colors that are in the range [0-255] per-component.

Comment: In fact, it almost looks like this is how you had your code originally. Using `GL_TRUE` for `normalized` indicates that you intended to store the vertex parameter for color as a fixed-point data type to begin with and want to dictate the behavior GLSL uses when it comes time to convert it to floating-point. This parameter is a no-op when you are already using a floating-point data type.